# Derivative of bilinear forms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to solve the following problems:

> 1. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear form.
>      Prove that it's differential is $$ Df_{(x,y)}(a,b) = f(x,b) + f(a,y).$$
> 2. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the cross product funtion, that is, $f(x,y) = x \times y$. Calulate it's derivate in the point $(x,y)$.

I know the definition of differentiability for funtions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. But here I am working with other funtions, so I don't know how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \sim \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: The range of the cross product function is $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you Umberto P. I already correct it.

Comment: @Siminore Uh, no, it's $\mathbb R^{2n}$. The square would hold for the tensor product.

Answer (score 8):

For the first part,

\begin{align}
Df_{(x,y)}(a,b) &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t = 0} f((x,y) + t(a,b))\\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t = 0} f(x + ta, y + tb)\\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t = 0} (f(x,y) + tf(x,b) + tf(a,y) + t^2f(a,b))\\
&= f(x,b) + f(a,y).
\end{align}

The bilinearity condition was used third line.

For the second part, show that $f$ is a bilinear form, and use the result in part 1 to find the derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)$.

Comment: I would like to know the proof of the identity $\begin{align}
Df_{(x,y)}(a,b) &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t = 0} f((x,y) + t(a,b))
\end{align}$ could you please provide me with a reference?

Comment: @Ronald it's by definition.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think you proved here that a bilinear form has a directional derivative in every direction, but that doesn't mean it's differentiable as shown here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982757/prove-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-directional-derivatives-every-direction/1982771        --- Although you have proven that provided $f$ is differentiable, the differential is what you propose.

Comment: @JamesWell the first question simply asks for the computation of the differential of $f$ at $(x,y)$, which I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Read part IV of Example 6.127 in https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/mathematical-methods. This is the simplest and most direct and natural way to answer the two proposed questions. Part I-Part III answer some side issues raised in this webpage. The proof given in part IV consists of two steps. The first step is to express the bilinear form as a product of three factors: a row vector, the matrix of the bilinear form with respect to the standard bases, and a column vector. Next step: the desired results follow directly from the definition of differential.