# Show that the following function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inner-products

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $U$ be a open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A: U \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ a differentiable aplication, with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ being the space of all linear applications $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$ Show that $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(x) = \left \langle A(x)x, x\right \rangle$ is differentiable and find $\phi'(x).$

One of my main problems is that $A$ is very much not a linear aplication, and all the tecniques that I know about differentiation seems to fail on this problem. I'm thinking that if I show, somehow, that $\phi$ is a composition of differentiable function, it may work, but I can't think of any combination that does the job. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
the evaluation
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\times\mathbb{R}^n
\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n
$$
$$(T,x)\longmapsto Tx$$
and the scalar product
$$\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$(x,y)\longmapsto⟨x,y⟩$$
are [bilinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120430/derivative-of-bilinear-forms), so...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get how this helps. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @BrunoTassone, bilinear functions are differentiable. See the link. You can wtrite your function as a composition of differentiable functions.